# How to get Resources from drawable folder - AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I am working on a game and I want to set the layout of game such that it works on Multiple device screens. So, instead of fetching images from `asset's folder`, I making looking for some way to fetch it from the `drawable folder`. So, that later on I can get the images according to the screen of the device.

**Update:**

I tried it using

```
mFaceTextureRegionLifeLine = (TiledTextureRegion) TextureRegionFactory.createFromResource(mTextureLifeLine, this, R.drawable.icon, 100, 100);
```

And, it fired me with and error below-

```
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.engine/com.engine.BallDemo}: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at com.engine.BallDemo.onLoadResources(BallDemo.java:132)
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreate(BaseGameActivity.java:57)
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-05 19:02:38.923: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4161):     ... 11 more
```

So, if it is possible let me know.
Thanks, Suri Sahani.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the method that will do this for you:

```
public static TextureRegion createFromResource(final Texture pTexture, final Context pContext, final int pDrawableResourceID, final int pTexturePositionX, final int pTexturePositionY)
```

If you need to create a tiled texture region, use this:

```
public static TiledTextureRegion createTiledFromResource(final Texture pTexture, final Context pContext, final int pDrawableResourceID, final int pTexturePositionX, final int pTexturePositionY, final int pTileColumns, final int pTileRows)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried that before also and it fired me an error, please look at my update question.

Comment: @suri sahani, Last two parameters are the number of tiles you have in columns and rows. For example if you have 6 tiles: 2 rows with 3 tiles in each, you should pass (3, 2) as parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Its working fine. but do tell me what are tiles.

Comment: @suri sahani, So what for do you need to make a tiled region? Actually, tiles are parts of an image, needed for animated sprites. Check the AnimatedSprites example in AndEngineExamples to see what effect does it give.

Comment: Well, I want to animate the images later on the Scene and that all I had done fetching images from assets folder. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If you simply specify the drawble id (Such as `R.drawable.icon`) then depending on your device it will pull it from the folder in `/res/` which is most appropriate to the device:

ie,

```
/res/drawable/icon.png 
/res/drawable-large/icon.png
```

Would mean large devices used the second png.

See the android site for more information on [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want fetch images from drawable folder, you should try this ->

```
Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
Resources r = ctx.getResources();
Drawable d = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.image_name);
```